# I would like to obtain a list of "regressions" in R

Tags: r

I have written the following code. I am extremely new to R. I don't have the knowledge of the language to debug this.

```
library(MASS)

RegressOnAll <- function() {
    li = list()
    nms = names(Boston)
    for (i in 2:length(nms)) {
        li[[i]] = lm(crim ~ nms[i], data=Boston)
    }
}

RegressOnAll()
```

An error message from the terminal

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = crim ~ nms[i], data = Boston, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'nms[i]')
Calls: RegressOnAll ... lm -> eval -> eval -> <Anonymous> -> model.frame.default
Execution halted
```

I am not sure what to do with this error.

My goal is to pick out regression coefficients and compare them with multiple regression coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `reformulate`

```
RegressOnAll <- function() {
    
    nms = setdiff(names(Boston), "crim")
    li <- vector('list', length(nms))
    for (i in seq_along(nms)) {
        li[[i]] = lm(reformulate(nms[i], response = "crim"), data=Boston)
    }
return(li)
}
```

-testing

```
> RegressOnAll()
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = reformulate(nms[i], response = "crim"), data = Boston)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           zn  
    4.45369     -0.07393  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = reformulate(nms[i], response = "crim"), data = Boston)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        indus  
    -2.0637       0.5098  


[[3]]
...
```